# Iterate in a javascript subobject with an unknown name

Tags: javascript

I'm parsong RSS news using javascript..
The object returned (from Yahoo YQL) has the news inside a **news** object.

Normally, it's inside this subobject:

```
news.results.item
```

So I would just iterate normally using:

```
news.results.item.forEach
```

Now it gets interesting when I'm loading multiple sources.. it can return stuff like

```
news.results.item (array[10])
news.results.entry (array[10])
news.results.banana (array[10])
```

My question is, how can I iterate inside these entries when I don't know the naming that will be returned.. is there a simple way to merge them all? (Using jQuery is fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all of the array properties on `news.results`:

```js
var news = {
    results: {
        item: ["a", "b", "c"],
        entry: ["d", "e", "f"],
        banana: ["g", "h", "i"]
    }
};
Object.keys(news.results).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = news.results[key];
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.forEach(function(entry) {
            console.log(entry);
        });
    }
});
```

And if you're looking for something specific and want to stop when you find it, you can use `some` instead of `forEach` or do a nested `find` (you'll need a `find` polyfill for some browsers still).

But if you *want* to combine them before searching, that's fairly easily done:

```js
var news = {
    results: {
        item: ["a", "b", "c"],
      entry: ["d", "e", "f"],
        banana: ["g", "h", "i"]
    }
};
var all = [];
Object.keys(news.results).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = news.results[key];
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        all.push.apply(all, value);
    }
});
all.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
});
```

*(Some people would use `reduce` for that. I think it obscures rather than aiding reading in cases like this where the accumulation value never actually changes.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `for..of` loop

```js
let news = {
  result: {
    item: [1,2,3],
    entry: [4,5,6],
    banana: [7,8,9]
  }
}

for (let key of Object.keys(news.result)) {
  console.log(`${key}:`);
  for (let entries of news.result[key]) {
    console.log(entries)
  }
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not certain what you mean? OP is expecting possibly more than single property at `result` object? E.g., `result` could contain `item`, `entry` and `banana`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder See updated post.

Comment: Yes, that fixes it. Beware of browser support for `Object.entries`, it's an ES2017 thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder See updated post. `Object.keys()` returns expected result by adjusting pattern. Initially interpreted Question as only one property would be set at object.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer as pointed out by T.J. Crowder

```js
var news = {
  results: {
    item: ["a", "b", "c"],
    entry: ["d", "e", "f"],
    banana: ["g", "h", "i"]
  }
};

for (var key in news.results) {
  console.log(key + " " + news.results[key])

}
```

Comment: There is **zero** need for jQuery here. It's 2016. Arrays have had `forEach` for several years.

Comment: arrays do, but objects do not support forEach